# Blackberry webworks. App crashes second time it runs

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am hoping you guys have an idea of something I can try as I am stuck. I have a blackberry app that has a few changes made to it. That is all done and working. But as the app is it seems to have a flaw. The first time I run the app it runs perfectly. No errors, everything is super fast and awesome. However the second time I run the app. The buttons do not work. I traced this in the logfile and got the following event.

Name - UI
Severity - Always logged.
GUID - bef92e11214401c3
Time - Aug01,2013 10:52:21

UIE - Cancelling tap due to edge detection: (284,474); OSTS: 436375

The device is a blackberry bold 9900. I have a blackberry bold 9900 simulator and the app runs perfectly on it. No cancelled taps, nothing. it is perfect. Also, If I run any other app then run this app, it crashes. I double checked the Json strings sent through. I checked the to ensure that it has web access. all is good. It runs 100% perfect the first time. If I close it and run it again, I cannot tap my buttons. Any info/ideas would be appreciated.

If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. I will answer them as best I can. I also discovered that if I run the app a few times after that, for a random amount, it runs perfectly again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. I did not provide code, so I doubt you could have found it. But this was what caused my problem. I had a line of code like follows...

```
 $('#home').on('pageinit', function () {//work stuffs}
```

Where it should have been...

```
 $('#home').bind('pageinit', function () {// work stuffs}
```

I have no idea why exactly... But this solved my issues.